# Trying to do a count query with subqueries and jointures

Tags: subquery, sql-server-express

I have tried different ways of achieving this task **with subqueries**

But finaly **tried it with jointures**. with little success

The main task is finding how many (so count them) COMMANDES (NCOM) that specify one or more PRODUITS in ACIER there are

```
 select count(NCOM) as COUNT
 from   Detail D, Produit P
 where  D.NPRO = P.NPRO
 and    P.LIBELLE = '%ACIER%'
```

It always gives me a 0 count

I don't know if it would be easier with subqueries but I'm not getting anywhere right now.

Below you can fin my tables create and insert

```
create table CLIENT
(NCLI char(4) not null,
 NOM  varchar(12) not null,
 ADRESSE varchar(20) not null,
 LOCALITE varchar(12) not null,
 CAT char(2),
 COMPTE decimal(9,2) not null,
 primary key (NCLI));

create table PRODUIT
(NPRO char(5) not null,
 LIBELLE varchar(20) not null,
 PRIX decimal(5,0) not null,
 QSTOCK decimal(6,0) not null,
 primary key (NPRO));

create table COMMANDE
(NCOM char(5) not null,
 NCLI char(4) not null,
 DATECOM datetime not null,
 primary key (NCOM),
 foreign key (NCLI) references CLIENT);

create table DETAIL
(NCOM char(5) not null,
 NPRO char(5) not null,
 QCOM decimal(4,0) not null,
 primary key (NCOM,NPRO),
 foreign key (NCOM) references COMMANDE,
 foreign key (NPRO) references PRODUIT);



insert into CLIENT values ('B112','HANSENNE'    ,'23, a. Dumont'       ,'Poitiers' ,'C1',1250.00);
insert into CLIENT values ('C123','MERCIER'     ,'25, r. Lemaitre'     ,'Namur'    ,'C1',-2300);
insert into CLIENT values ('B332','MONTI'       ,'112, r. Neuve'       ,'Geneve'   ,'B2',0);
insert into CLIENT values ('F010','TOUSSAINT'   ,'5, r. Godefroid'     ,'Poitiers' ,'C1',0);
insert into CLIENT values ('K111','VANBIST'     ,'180, r. Florimont'   ,'Lille'    ,'B1',720);
insert into CLIENT values ('S127','VANDERKA'    ,'3, av. des Roses'    ,'Namur'    ,'C1',-4580);
insert into CLIENT values ('B512','GILLET'      ,'14, r. de l''Ete'    ,'Toulouse' ,'B1',-8700);
insert into CLIENT values ('B062','GOFFIN'      ,'72, r. de la Gare'   ,'Namur'    ,'B2',-3200);
insert into CLIENT values ('C400','FERARD'      ,'65, r. du Tertre'    ,'Poitiers' ,'B2',350);
insert into CLIENT values ('C003','AVRON'       ,'8, ch. de la Cure'   ,'Toulouse' ,'B1',-1700);
insert into CLIENT values ('K729','NEUMAN'      ,'40, r. Bransart'     ,'Toulouse' ,NULL,0);
insert into CLIENT values ('F011','PONCELET'    ,'17, Clos des Erables','Toulouse' ,'B2',0);
insert into CLIENT values ('L422','FRANCK'      ,'60, r. de Wepion'    ,'Namur'    ,'C1',0);
insert into CLIENT values ('S712','GUILLAUME'   ,'14a, ch. des Roses'  ,'Paris'    ,'B1',0);
insert into CLIENT values ('D063','MERCIER'       ,'201, bvd du Nord'  ,'Toulouse' ,NULL,-2250);
insert into CLIENT values ('F400','JACOB'       ,'78, ch. du Moulin'   ,'Bruxelles','C2',0);

insert into PRODUIT values ('CS262','CHEV. SAPIN 200x6x2',  75,  45);
insert into PRODUIT values ('CS264','CHEV. SAPIN 200x6x4', 120,2690);
insert into PRODUIT values ('CS464','CHEV. SAPIN 400x6x4', 220, 450);
insert into PRODUIT values ('PA45' ,'POINTE ACIER 45 (1K)',105, 580);
insert into PRODUIT values ('PA60' ,'POINTE ACIER 60 (1K)', 95, 134);
insert into PRODUIT values ('PH222','PL. HETRE 200x20x2',  230, 782);
insert into PRODUIT values ('PS222','PL. SAPIN 200x20x2',  185,1220);

insert into COMMANDE values ('30178','K111','20081221');
insert into COMMANDE values ('30179','C400','20081222');
insert into COMMANDE values ('30182','S127','20081223');
insert into COMMANDE values ('30184','C400','20081223');
insert into COMMANDE values ('30185','F011','20090102');
insert into COMMANDE values ('30186','C400','20090102');
insert into COMMANDE values ('30188','B512','20090103');

insert into DETAIL values ('30178','CS464',25);
insert into DETAIL values ('30179','PA60',20);
insert into DETAIL values ('30179','CS262',60);
insert into DETAIL values ('30182','PA60',30);
insert into DETAIL values ('30184','CS464',120);
insert into DETAIL values ('30184','PA45',20);
insert into DETAIL values ('30185','PA60',15);
insert into DETAIL values ('30185','PS222',600);
insert into DETAIL values ('30185','CS464',260);
insert into DETAIL values ('30186','PA45',3);
insert into DETAIL values ('30188','PA60',70);
insert into DETAIL values ('30188','PH222',92);
insert into DETAIL values ('30188','CS464',180);
insert into DETAIL values ('30188','PA45',22);
```

Comment: detail table doesn't exist..Please add the whole schema..

Comment: You are using old style of joins. Use the JOIN keyword instead of comma (,). Ask yourself what is the meaning of ` where P.LIBELLE = '%ACIER%'`. Please read the basics of SQL before you learn more. Teach yourself SQL in 10 mins by Ben Forta is a decent crash course, but not a good way to learn DB and SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use LIKE instead of =.
Like this

```
    select count(NCOM) as COUNT
 from   Detail D, Produit P
 where  D.NPRO = P.NPRO
 and    P.LIBELLE LIKE '%ACIER%'
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I added distinct also and the result was perfect, maybe it woulb de still easier with subqueries

Answer (score 0):

In your where clausule is = . You must use LIKE... LIKE '%ACIER%'

```
 select count(NCOM) as COUNT
 from   DETAIL D
 JOIN PRODUIT P ON D.NPRO = P.NPRO
 where P.LIBELLE LIKE '%ACIER%'
```